# How to directly get the father node?

Tags: javascript

I want to select the td which contain a sonNode input and it's type is text
.

```
<td><input type="button" value="submit"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="test"></td>
```

My js code

```
var fob = document.querySelector("td input[type='text']");
fob.parentNode;
```

Is there a some way to position directly to the `td` tag in my case which contain a sonNode input and it's type is text?

```
document.querySelector("td input[type='text']").parentNode.nodeName
```

It is a indirect way,get son node first ,then go to parent node.
I expect some expression directly to get the `td`.

```
 document.querySelector("expression")
```

To make `document.querySelector("expression").nodeName` just be equal to `td`.

Comment: No, it is not possible, the current CSS level does't have parent selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put - no.

If you think about it, logically, you are searching for an element matching your criteria, and then expanding to its parent. For instance:

"Find a pencil inside one of these 5 boxes. Take the box with the pencil."

In terms of shorthand coding solution, you can directly call the `parentNode` straight from the execution line, and even select the attribute you want to pick:

```js
var fob = document.querySelector("td input[type='text']").parentNode.getAttribute('name');
alert(fob);
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>test</td></tr>
<tr><td name='here'><input type="text" placeholder="123"/></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT**
Here is an example with VIM:

```
vim example.txt
```

This only works when you are in the same directory, a.k.a. bash doesn't have parents to consider.

If you are in the absolute root, and you type that command, but the file is located inside `/home/me/example.txt` you will not edit the file, you will have to type:

```
vim /home/me/example.txt
```

Comment: That is my method ,you select child node first then get its father node.

Comment: I don't think you've read my reply entirely. Please re-read it and pay attention to the logical example provided in the middle. Since you also appear to be more UNIX experienced, let me give you an example with vim as well.